# Understanding the Google Sign-in flow with token validation

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services, google-authentication

In my Android app I want the users to be able to exchange messages.

To authenticate the users I want to use the [Google+ Sign-in for Android](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in) provided by the Google Play Services. The flow currently looks like this:

1. First run: Display "Sign-in with Google" button.
2. The user clicks on the button and grants permission.
3. The user enters a message and sends it. In the background I request a token (`ya29...`) with `GoogleAuthUtil.getTokenWithNotification(...)`, attach the token to the message and send it to the server (`HTTPS POST`).

On the server side I receive the message+token and call the [tokeninfo endpoint](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=ya29...). Then I validate the `audience` field. If everything looks good I grab the `user_id` from the tokeninfo endpoint and forward the message to the recipient.

My questions are:

- Is this flow correct, or am I missing something?
- Do I really have to call `GoogleAuthUtil.getTokenWithNotification(...)` for every single message?
- Do I really have to validate the token with the tokeninfo endpoint every time?

This is the first time I'm using this API and OAuth in general, so I'm not quite sure if I understood the concept completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this flow correct, or am I missing something?

So far everything is right. But I would recommend another approach on the server side. You do not need to do a HTTP request to Google (and parse the JSON afterwards), you can simply use a library from Google for that. Take a look at the bottom of [Using OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2?hl=de).

Using code from [Verifying Back-End Calls from Android Apps](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html)
 you can do this:

```
Checker checker = new Checker();
GoogleIdToken.Payload payload = checker.check(token);
String mail = payload.getEmail();
```

> Do I really have to call GoogleAuthUtil.getTokenWithNotification(...) for every single message?

No, you don't. The token is valid for some time (I think it was one hour). Therefore store the token in your app and send it to server. If the authorization fails on server side, because the token is expired, you can return HTTP 401 (unauthorized) and your app knows that it has to generate a new token.

> Do I really have to validate the token with the tokeninfo endpoint every time?

Of course you have to validate the token. You have to prevent that requests are faked. If you only accept valid tokens it is more complicated to send wrong data to your server.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still confused about the server side validation though. I looked into the [Google Client PHP library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/installation) and managed to validate the token with the `tokeninfo` method of the `Google_Service_Oauth2` class. However the method seems to just call the tokeninfo endpoint, too. Depending on the number of messages this could result in a large number of requests. Is this really the correct way to authenticate the user?!

Comment: Sure the Google library need to communicate with the Google API. But in my opinion it is better to use a lib from Google for that than implementing it yourself.